# How to have an elpy breakpoint in a different file

Tags: python, elpy, debug

When running tests or scripts using elpy, I would like to set a breakpoint in a different file than the file that is the start of execution. However, from documentation, I see I can only set a breakpoint in the current buffer.

Is there an accepted way to have breakpoints across multiple files like IDEs typically offer?

This question has been originaly asked by [Mittenchops](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/15646/mittenchops) but was deleted. I had the same issue so will post the original question and an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened a pull request that solves this ([PR2007](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/pull/2007)). To enable breakpoint interruption just replace your local `elpy-shell.el` (on my machine it was located in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/elpy-20220922.2253`) file with the one from this pull request [PR2007](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/pull/2007) and delete the elpy-shell.elc. Now the debugger should also interrupt execution at breakpoints set in other buffers that the buffer you are executing.

Hopefully this PR will be merged and this functionality will be included in the normal elpy package on elpa.